# How do I make an aggregation pipeline for grouping an array of objects by common value in MongoDB?

Tags: mongodb

I have a document that looks like this:

```
[{
  "_id": {
    "$oid": "60dd583e38a494001e7cbe01"
  },
  "firstLogIn": {
    "$date": "2021-07-01T05:51:30.253Z"
  },
  "lastLoggedIn": {
    "$date": "2021-07-01T05:51:30.253Z"
  },
  "name": "First Last",
  "provider": "google",
  "googleID": "some google ID",
  "email": "email@gmail.com",
  "picture": "link to picture",
  "bookmarks": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb42f1137d8b00035e32a0"
      },
      "name": "Long Island City",
      "country": "US",
      "latitude": 34.127871999999996,
      "longitude": -80.84848640000001
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb42f3137d8b00035e32a3"
      },
      "name": "Winnsboro",
      "country": "US",
      "latitude": 34.40692674307974,
      "longitude": -81.09448258878032
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb42f5137d8b00035e32a6"
      },
      "name": "Inman Mills",
      "country": "US",
      "latitude": 35.033386821812115,
      "longitude": -82.12719743253032
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb42f7137d8b00035e32a9"
      },
      "name": "Hamblen",
      "country": "US",
      "latitude": 36.21770383049459,
      "longitude": -83.15991227628032
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb42fa137d8b00035e32ac"
      },
      "name": "Webster City",
      "country": "US",
      "latitude": 42.50324651998116,
      "longitude": -93.71055864882939
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb42fd137d8b00035e32af"
      },
      "name": "Burney",
      "country": "US",
      "latitude": 40.96202110727774,
      "longitude": -121.30821489882939
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb42ff137d8b00035e32b2"
      },
      "name": "Cabullona",
      "country": "MX",
      "latitude": 31.22073971753058,
      "longitude": -109.53087114882939
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb4302137d8b00035e32b5"
      },
      "name": "Panindícuaro",
      "country": "MX",
      "latitude": 20.033688711184624,
      "longitude": -101.70860552382939
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb4305137d8b00035e32b8"
      },
      "name": "La Flecha",
      "country": "HN",
      "latitude": 15.218944667538244,
      "longitude": -88.43712114882939
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb4309137d8b00035e32bb"
      },
      "name": "Morrito",
      "country": "NI",
      "latitude": 11.586000022019745,
      "longitude": -84.92149614882939
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb430d137d8b00035e32be"
      },
      "name": "Zopilotepe",
      "country": "HN",
      "latitude": 14.581934231038352,
      "longitude": -86.28380083632939
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb4310137d8b00035e32c1"
      },
      "name": "Tiquisate",
      "country": "GT",
      "latitude": 14.262731498702198,
      "longitude": -91.42540239882939
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb4314137d8b00035e32c4"
      },
      "name": "Departamento del Petén",
      "country": "GT",
      "latitude": 16.887029154799734,
      "longitude": -90.01915239882939
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb431a137d8b00035e32c7"
      },
      "name": "Bonanza",
      "country": "NI",
      "latitude": 13.9217498394043,
      "longitude": -84.70176958632939
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60ee1152aaf6f900038fb0ad"
      },
      "name": "Wellsville",
      "country": "US",
      "latitude": 38.65294932728673,
      "longitude": -95.13620612656251
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60ef63479505990003b1d082"
      },
      "name": "Whitmire",
      "country": "US",
      "latitude": 34.57175229051191,
      "longitude": -81.72807761825985
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60ef65d19505990003b1d089"
      },
      "name": "Freeman",
      "country": "US",
      "latitude": 43.244639835984984,
      "longitude": -97.2531191188387
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60ef65d69505990003b1d08c"
      },
      "name": "Arco",
      "country": "US",
      "latitude": 43.53206020360104,
      "longitude": -113.6447206813387
    },
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60f359f505721a00035383e1"
      },
      "name": "Auburn",
      "country": "US",
      "latitude": 36.796308646958956,
      "longitude": -86.74567294258286
    }
  ],
  "__v": 0
}]
```

Basically, what I want is to retrieve the data such that the bookmarks subarray has a subarray containing the bookmarks with the specific country.

So instead of

```
"bookmarks": [
    {
      "_id": {
        "$oid": "60eb42f1137d8b00035e32a0"
      },
      "name": "Long Island City",
      "country": "US",
      "latitude": 34.127871999999996,
      "longitude": -80.84848640000001
    }
```

it'll be

```
"bookmarks": [
    "US": [
          {
            "_id": {
              "$oid": "60eb42f1137d8b00035e32a0"
            },
            "name": "Long Island City",
            "country": "US",
            "latitude": 34.127871999999996,
            "longitude": -80.84848640000001
          }]
]
```

while still keeping the user information such as the name, provider, etc...

Currently, my pipeline looks like this:

```
[
  {
    '$match': {
      '_id': new ObjectId('60dd583e38a494001e7cbe01')
    }
  }, {
    '$unwind': {
      'path': '$bookmarks', 
      'preserveNullAndEmptyArrays': false
    }
  }
]
```

which separates which item in the subarray but I'm not sure how to put them back in the way I want them to look.

Comment: Is [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/ROKr9P0BIQA) what are you looking for? I can add an answer to explain better if you want.

Comment: Kind of. Is it possible to keep the user information like the name, email, etc?

Comment: Something like [this](https://mongoplayground.net/p/tvYCA16nmxd)?

Comment: Without the duplicate, sorry for inconveniencing. I want it to look like this:


`"name": "First Last",
  "provider": "google",
  "googleID": "some google ID",
  "email": "email@gmail.com",
  "picture": "link to picture",
  "bookmarks": [
      {
          "US" : [
              data.....
           ],
          "GT" : [
              data.....
           ], ....
      }
  ]`

Comment: Having the value of a country as a field name is somewhat of an anti-pattern, which is one reason this is a challenging request.

Comment: What would be the correct way of doing this? Maybe through node?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is an example, but the output does not use a data point as a field name, rather it puts the country names in a field called country...

**Aggregation**

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    {
        $match:
        {
            "_id": new ObjectId("60dd583e38a494001e7cbe01")
        }
    },
    { $unwind: "$bookmarks" },
    { 
        $group:
        {
            "_id": "$bookmarks.country",
            "bookmarks": { "$push": "$bookmarks" },
            "originalId": {"$first": "$_id" },
            "firstLogIn": {"$first": "$firstLogIn"},
            "lastLoggedIn": {"$first": "$lastLoggedIn"},
            "name": {"$first": "$name"},
            "provider": {"$first": "$provider"},
            "googleID": {"$first": "$googleID"},
            "email": {"$first": "$email"},
            "picture": {"$first": "$picture"}
        }
    },
    {
        $project:
        {
            "bookmark.country": "$_id",
            "bookmark.details" : "$bookmarks",
            "_id": "$originalId",
            "firstLogIn": 1,
            "lastLoggedIn": 1,
            "name": 1,
            "provider": 1,
            "googleID": 1,
            "email": 1,
            "picture": 1
        }
    },
    {
        $group:
        {
            "_id": "$_id",
            "firstLogIn": {"$first": "$firstLogIn"},
            "lastLoggedIn": {"$first": "$lastLoggedIn"},
            "name": {"$first": "$name"},
            "provider": {"$first": "$provider"},
            "googleID": {"$first": "$googleID"},
            "email": {"$first": "$email"},
            "picture": {"$first": "$picture"},
            "bookmarks": { "$push": "$bookmark" }
        }
    }
]).pretty()
```

**Aggregation Explanation**

This aggregation has 5 stages...

1. $match
2. $unwind
3. $group
4. $project
5. $group

Step 1 - Start by matching to an _id value.

Step 2 - Next, perform an unwinding of the array.

Step 3 - Group by country name.  Since the unwind'ed documents share the same _id, firstLogin, LastLoggedIn, etc. we can refer to the $first occurrence of these to retain them in the pipeline.

Step 4 - Use a $project projection stage to rename fields, notably the grouping in step 3 caused the country name to be the _id.  Need to shift this back into a subdocument called bookmark.country.

Step 5 - Final step - regroup by the original _id value.  Since we performed a $match in the first step, all documents at this point in the pipeline have the same _id value, but by regrouping we can add a $push accumulator to place the details into an array called "bookmarks".

**Example output**

```
{
    "_id" : ObjectId("60dd583e38a494001e7cbe01"),
    "firstLogIn" : ISODate("2021-07-01T05:51:30.253Z"),
    "lastLoggedIn" : ISODate("2021-07-01T05:51:30.253Z"),
    "name" : "First Last",
    "provider" : "google",
    "googleID" : "some google ID",
    "email" : "email@gmail.com",
    "picture" : "link to picture",
    "bookmarks" : [
        {
            "country" : "MX",
            "details" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60eb42ff137d8b00035e32b2"),
                    "name" : "Cabullona",
                    "country" : "MX",
                    "latitude" : 31.22073971753058,
                    "longitude" : -109.53087114882939
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60eb4302137d8b00035e32b5"),
                    "name" : "Panindícuaro",
                    "country" : "MX",
                    "latitude" : 20.033688711184624,
                    "longitude" : -101.70860552382939
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "country" : "US",
            "details" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60eb42f1137d8b00035e32a0"),
                    "name" : "Long Island City",
                    "country" : "US",
                    "latitude" : 34.127871999999996,
                    "longitude" : -80.84848640000001
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60eb42f3137d8b00035e32a3"),
                    "name" : "Winnsboro",
                    "country" : "US",
                    "latitude" : 34.40692674307974,
                    "longitude" : -81.09448258878032
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60eb42f5137d8b00035e32a6"),
                    "name" : "Inman Mills",
                    "country" : "US",
                    "latitude" : 35.033386821812115,
                    "longitude" : -82.12719743253032
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60eb42f7137d8b00035e32a9"),
                    "name" : "Hamblen",
                    "country" : "US",
                    "latitude" : 36.21770383049459,
                    "longitude" : -83.15991227628032
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60eb42fa137d8b00035e32ac"),
                    "name" : "Webster City",
                    "country" : "US",
                    "latitude" : 42.50324651998116,
                    "longitude" : -93.71055864882939
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60eb42fd137d8b00035e32af"),
                    "name" : "Burney",
                    "country" : "US",
                    "latitude" : 40.96202110727774,
                    "longitude" : -121.30821489882939
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60ee1152aaf6f900038fb0ad"),
                    "name" : "Wellsville",
                    "country" : "US",
                    "latitude" : 38.65294932728673,
                    "longitude" : -95.13620612656251
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60ef63479505990003b1d082"),
                    "name" : "Whitmire",
                    "country" : "US",
                    "latitude" : 34.57175229051191,
                    "longitude" : -81.72807761825985
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60ef65d19505990003b1d089"),
                    "name" : "Freeman",
                    "country" : "US",
                    "latitude" : 43.244639835984984,
                    "longitude" : -97.2531191188387
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60ef65d69505990003b1d08c"),
                    "name" : "Arco",
                    "country" : "US",
                    "latitude" : 43.53206020360104,
                    "longitude" : -113.6447206813387
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60f359f505721a00035383e1"),
                    "name" : "Auburn",
                    "country" : "US",
                    "latitude" : 36.796308646958956,
                    "longitude" : -86.74567294258286
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "country" : "HN",
            "details" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60eb4305137d8b00035e32b8"),
                    "name" : "La Flecha",
                    "country" : "HN",
                    "latitude" : 15.218944667538244,
                    "longitude" : -88.43712114882939
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60eb430d137d8b00035e32be"),
                    "name" : "Zopilotepe",
                    "country" : "HN",
                    "latitude" : 14.581934231038352,
                    "longitude" : -86.28380083632939
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "country" : "NI",
            "details" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60eb4309137d8b00035e32bb"),
                    "name" : "Morrito",
                    "country" : "NI",
                    "latitude" : 11.586000022019745,
                    "longitude" : -84.92149614882939
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60eb431a137d8b00035e32c7"),
                    "name" : "Bonanza",
                    "country" : "NI",
                    "latitude" : 13.9217498394043,
                    "longitude" : -84.70176958632939
                }
            ]
        },
        {
            "country" : "GT",
            "details" : [
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60eb4310137d8b00035e32c1"),
                    "name" : "Tiquisate",
                    "country" : "GT",
                    "latitude" : 14.262731498702198,
                    "longitude" : -91.42540239882939
                },
                {
                    "_id" : ObjectId("60eb4314137d8b00035e32c4"),
                    "name" : "Departamento del Petén",
                    "country" : "GT",
                    "latitude" : 16.887029154799734,
                    "longitude" : -90.01915239882939
                }
            ]
        }
    ]
}
```

**GOTCHAS**

If you add fields to your document you need to remember to add them to the aggregation otherwise they will not be included in the output.  This strategy requires the first stage is a $match on field _id.  Any other field will cause the 5th step of regrouping to fail as there are more than one original _id field, thus $first will not work.